# How to split java string to get 5 substring on the delimiter ","

Tags: java, string, split

I am having a java string as response from server`["This is my "json response", "jshj" "," "sdjfh,sfjg" ",""Abs, "jshj" ",""Abs, "jshj" ",""Abs, "jshj"",""Abs, "jshj" "].`
I want to split the string to 5 substring on the delimiter "," so that I can store the result into array.

Expected output is :

> This is my "json response", "jshj"   "sdjfh,sfjg" "Abs, "jshj"  "Abs,
>   "jshj"  "Abs, "jshj" "Abs, "jshj"

Following is my approach:

```
String arrayGenerated[] =result.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\"]", "").split(__________,5);
        return arrayGenerated;
```

Please suggest what should I mention in the split part.

Comment: Please format you code, please.

Comment: Please also fix your raw server response to distinguish between literal and non literal double quotes.

Comment: Use a json parser, it is more safer

Comment: @ropu provide proper sample json

Answer (score 0):

After parsing your server response you can use **String.split("regular expression")** method to split the response.

```
String a = "[\"This is my \"json response\", \"jshj\" \",\" \"sdjfh,sfjg\" \",\"\"Abs, \"jshj\" \",\"\"Abs, \"jshj\" \",\"\"Abs, \"jshj\"\",\"\"Abs, \"jshj\" \"]";
String arr[] = a.split("\",\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test1222 {
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        String fileName = "C:\\\filepath";
        List<String> list = null;
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            list = stream.collect(Collectors.toList()); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String str = list.get(0);
        String str1 = str.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","");

        String[] strArr = str1.split(",");
        List<String> resultArr = Arrays.asList(strArr);
        List<String> result = resultArr.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

        result.forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the server response and then split the response as follows,

```
String str = "[\"This is my \"json response\", \"jshj\" \",\" \"sdjfh,sfjg\" \",\"\"Abs, \"jshj\" \",\"\"Abs, \"jshj\" \",\"\"Abs, \"jshj\"\",\"\"Abs, \"jshj\" \"]";

str = str.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", ""); // To remove []

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split(",")); // Simply separate words by comma to a list that you can iterate

for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String next = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(next);
}
```

And if you need to remove double quotes from the server response you can use the following statement,

```
str.replaceAll("\"", "")
```